# How can I make bullets rotate the other way with the Skimmer?

Tags: diep.io

Whenever I play Skimmer, the rotating bullets always rotate clockwise:

[image: Skimmer and bullet with arrows showing rotation of bullet]

However, in team battles, my teammates have been shooting bullets that rotate counter-clockwise. How can I do just that?

Comment: May I have a reason for the downvote on both the question and answer? I believe this is not a well-known thing to do as evidenced by the loads of people asking about it on Discord.

Comment: Does the rotation have an actual in-game effect, or is it just a little neat thing? If it doesn't do anything, I'd question the utility of asking this.

Comment: @Frank The bullets when fired close together would make a larger storm overall increasing the defense of the Skimmer behind that bullet wall.

Comment: Yeah, *but how does rotation help with that*? It sounds like just shooting will give you that protection.

Comment: The downvote was me, because I don't agree that making questions that haven't been asked just to self-answer them is useful.

Comment: @Studoku Then why is that a feature?

Answer (score 1):

If you hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> while shooting a bullet with <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd>, <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, or having auto-fire enabled with <kbd>E</kbd>, it will face the other way.